# I have a problem with setting up javascript cron

Tags: javascript, node.js, cron

I need help with setting up the cron time of executing. I have this one:

```
cron.schedule('1,2,4,5 * * * *', () => {
  console.log('running every minute 1, 2, 4 and 5');
});
```

but instead doing it every minute 1,2,3,4,5, I want to execute every minute of the hour 247

Comment: Then don't say `1,2,4,5`?

Comment: be more accurate, how to write it

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation for the module you're using?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're using [`node-cron`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron).

The cron syntax for `node-cron` looks like this:

```
  ┌────────────── second (optional)
  │ ┌──────────── minute
  │ │ ┌────────── hour
  │ │ │ ┌──────── day of month
  │ │ │ │ ┌────── month
  │ │ │ │ │ ┌──── day of week
  │ │ │ │ │ │
  │ │ │ │ │ │
  * * * * * *
```

So if you want to schedule a task every minute, you could write it in one of the following ways:

```
// schedule to run every minute (at 0 seconds on the clock)
// e.g. this will run at 00:00:00, 00:01:00, 00:02:00, ... (hh:mm:ss)
cron.schedule('* * * * *', () => {
  console.log('this will run every minute');
});

// same as above, but with explicit 0 seconds
cron.schedule('0 * * * * *', () => {
  console.log('this will also run every minute');
});

// run every minute, but at the 30 second mark
// e.g. this will run at 00:00:30, 00:01:30, 00:02:30, ... (hh:mm:ss)
cron.schedule('30 * * * * *', () => {
  console.log('this will also run every minute (when seconds hits 30)');
});
```